# How to animate only the camera?

Tags: mesh

So  i have a scene with a few objects, and a water simulation in the scene. However I want to animate the camera turning around in the scene, while the water simulation is frozen in time. So something like a time freeze effect. But when ever I try to render an animation it renders the water simulation too. I just need one frame of the water simulation. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the scene to a new one (you can call it "freezed"), then choose the frame you want to freeze, select the fluid object and apply the simulator modifier.
At this point you can do every animation you need without affecting the shape of the fluid.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is whether this affects the original scene.  You might want to click the [2] next to the object's name in the object panel to decouple it from the object in the original scene.  (linking of datablocks is an often-overlooked tool/pitfall in blender).

Comment: Can i do the same with particle system? There is only a "convert option" instead of apply for particles.

Comment: Nevermind I found a way to fix it (sort of), just increased lifetime and start/end values.